# Minimum MCU clock frequency to process an analog signal with a max. frequency component of 50 kHz

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, frequency, clock, msp430

An MCU requiring 4 clock cycles to process a sample has to sample an analog signal having a maximum frequency component of 50 kHz. What should be the minimum clock frequency of the MCU?

This image was taken in the embedded system design course of NPTEL. I found it interesting and challenging.

[image]

Comment: It depends on whether it uses multiple ADCs or not. This sounds like homework so what have you done to try and find an answer by your own research?

Comment: What does Nyquist mean to the minimum sampling frequency?  Add your answer to the question.  It should be obvious from there.

Comment: What's the bandwidth of the signal? Maximum frequency component doesn't tell you much if the signal is bandwidth limited.

Comment: Following Stainlesssteelrat comment sampling should be 100kHz. MCU cycle 100000/sec multiply 4 times. Closest answer 420.

Comment: @Andyaka I tried it, but I couldn't understand it, that's why I'm reaching out. Also, it is an assessment, but I approached only after they revealed the answers. So I think it's fair enough

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Okay got it! Minimum twice the max freq. So is multiplied by 4, should result in the clock cycle.

Comment: Write it up as an answer and welcome to the community.